# Aligning histogram plots

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a given data set, and I want to compare the histograms of this data when represented as a bar histogram and a line histogram. Specifically, I want to use

```
myhist = histogram(mydata)
```

to get the bar histogram, and plot on the same figure a line histogram using

```
mylinehist = plot(myhist.Values)
```

However, when I do that, I get the following figure

[image]

It seems like the line histogram mimics the shape of the bar histogram, but offsets it by a certain amount on the x-axis. Is there a way to align the two so I can have them overlapping? I tried using a command like

```
align([mylinelist,myhist],'Left','None')
```

but to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the x-axis values for your line plot. These should be the midpoints of your histogram bins.

Try:

```
midpts = myhist.BinEdges + (myhist.BinWidth / 2);

plot(midpts(1:myhist.NumBins), myhist.Values);
```